# SwiftUI - Is there a way to have draggable views inside a list and have said list scroll?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am having trouble with a list's scrolling when the views inside it have a `.gesture(DragGesture())` modifier. When I try to scroll the list if I tapped on said view when scrolling then the list won't scroll.

Say I have this list right here:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
        RowView()
    }
}
```

And the `RowView` is defined like this:

```swift
struct ThreadRow: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
                    .onChanged { ... }
                    .onEnded { ... }
            )
    }
}
```

Then the list won't work properly.

I have tried replacing the list with a `ScrollView { LazyVStack { ... } }` but that inteoduces an entirely new problem: when scrolling, if I scroll slightly diagonally instead of straight vertically, the `DragGesture` begins but doesn't end.